Confusion Regarding Orientation and Surface Normal in Stokes' Theorem Application
Problem Statement:
(a) Show that the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 20$ and the cone $z^2 = (x-2)^2 + y^2$, $z \geq 0$, intersect along a curve on the cylinder $((x-1)^2 + y^2 = 9)$.
(b) Calculate $\oint_{\gamma} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r}$, where $\mathbf{F} = (e^x, z^2, xyz)$ and $\gamma$ is the intersection curve from part (a), oriented counterclockwise when viewed from the origin.

My Approach:
I identified the surface $Y$ as the part of the sphere that lies above the cone and within the cylinder. I then used Stokes' theorem to convert the line integral into a surface integral:
$$
\oint_{\gamma} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r} = \iint_Y (\nabla \times \mathbf{F}) \cdot \mathbf{\hat{N}} \, dS
$$
I calculated the curl of $\mathbf{F}$ and found the surface normal to the sphere at the intersection with the cylinder. The normal vector $\mathbf{\hat{N}}$ I computed has a positive $z$-component.
However, in my solution, it suggests that I need to add a negative sign in front of the integral due to an orientation correction.

My Confusion:
The problem statement clearly says that the curve $\gamma$ is oriented counterclockwise when viewed from the origin, which should imply an outward-pointing normal vector according to the right-hand rule. Since my normal vector has a positive $z$-component, I'm confused as to why a negative sign correction is necessary.

Does this mean I have misunderstood the orientation or the application of the right-hand rule?
Is there some subtlety in the interpretation of the surface normal direction that I'm missing?

Any clarification on this would be greatly appreciated!

Exactly, 9*pi to be specific!

The right-hand rule implies that the curve is counter clockwise when viewed from outside of the sphere. Viewed from the origin you have to reverse that orientation.
